# How to copy data from a report to a sheet?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm looking to create a scheduled job to update the existing cell values in a sheet with data from a report. What would be an approach to take using the API?

Has anyone done this before? Looking at the docs, I think I would need to:

- (report) copy cells
- (sheet) update the existing data from some cells, others have formulas that i wish to retain

Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read the data in a Report and use that to update cells in a Sheet. To get started you would use the [GET Report](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-report) request and to update cells in a Sheet you would use the [Update Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-rows) request. You can also use the [Add Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#add-rows) request to add a new row to the Sheet instead.
A lot of how this would be implemented is dependent on the programming language you will be using and how you will be hosting your code for where it will run from.
The are multiple [SDKs](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform) for the Smartsheet API that you can bring into your project and we might have one in the language you will be using. There is also a [Getting Started](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#getting-started) section of the API docs that goes over making your first requests.